# Are Java DirectByteBuffer wrappers garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, bytebuffer

I understand that when a directbytebuffer is allocated, its not subject to garbage collection, but what I'm wondering is if the *wrapping* object is garbage collected.

For example, if I allocated a new DirectByteBuffer dbb, and then duplicated(shallow copied) it using dbb.duplicate(), I'd have two wrappers around the same chunk of memory.

Are those wrappers subject to garbage collection? If I did

```
while(true){
    DirectByteBuffer dbb2 = dbb.duplicate();
}
```

Would I eventually OOM myself?

Comment: Actually, a DirectByteBuffer and it's native memory _might_ be garbage collected. It uses a PhantomReference to release the native allocated memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Sun JDK, a `java.nio.DirectByteBuffer`—created by [`ByteBuffer#allocateDirect(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29)—has a field of type `sun.misc.Cleaner`, which extends [`java.lang.ref.PhantomReference`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html).

When this `Cleaner` (remember, a subtype of `PhantomReference`) gets collected and is about to move into the associated `ReferenceQueue`, the collection-related thread running through the nested type `ReferenceHandler` has a special case treatment of `Cleaner` instances: it downcasts and calls on `Cleaner#clean()`, which eventually makes its way back to calling on `DirectByteBuffer$Deallocator#run()`, which in turn calls on `Unsafe#freeMemory(long)`. Wow.

It's rather circuitous, and I was surprised to not see any use of `Object#finalize()` in play. The Sun developers must have had their reasons for tying this in even closer to the collection and reference management subsystem.

In short, you won't run out of memory by virtue of abandoning references to `DirectByteBuffer` instances, so long as the garbage collector has a chance to notice the abandonment and its reference handling thread makes progress through the calls described above.

Comment: note that if you are using `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` then you may encounter more `OutOfMemory` errors with `allocateDirect`.  The allocation tries to reserve memory and calls `System.gc()` if it cannot in order to trigger the reclaim of the the `PhantomReference`.

Comment: The reason is that Java was and is moving away from `finalize`. In fact, it will eventually be removed. The Cleaner mechanism is very similar, except for some implementation details that make it more performant and fixes some corner cases.

Comment: The more interesting thing is that DirectByteBuffer is not AutoCloseable and can’t be freed manually. This has negative consequences such as needing a super-ugly manual GC. However, the designers wanted to avoid putting a check on whether or not it’s closed on every read in order to get the absolute highest performance.

Answer (score 5):

A direct `ByteBuffer` object is just like any other object: it can be garbage-collected.

The memory used by a direct buffer will be released when the `ByteBuffer` object is GC'd (this is not explicitly stated for `ByteBuffer`, but is implied by the documentation of `MappedByteBuffer`).

Where things get interesting is when you've filled your virtual memory space with direct buffers, but still have lots of room in the heap. It turns out that (at least on the Sun JVM), running out of virtual space when allocating a direct buffer will trigger a GC of the Java heap. Which may collect unreferenced direct buffers and free their virtual memory commitment.

If you're running on a 64-bit machine, you should use `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`, which puts an upper limit on the number of buffers that you can allocate (and also triggers GC when you hit that limit).

Comment: How does using DirectByteBuffers help with garbage collection pauses, ala TerraCotta's BigMemory?

Comment: @Li Pi: because you can store a lot of serialized Java objects in one direct buffer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with “virtual space,” which is infinite on 64bit. This is about running out of actual memory because the GC doesn’t directly know about memory pressure of direct buffers (like it does with heap memory) and doesn’t fire in time. The manual gc is an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code to `DirectByteBuffer` it just returns a new instance, so no, you won't OOM yourself.

As long as the rest of your code doesn't hold onto a reference to the original `dbb` then that object will get garbage collected as normal. The extra `dbb2` objects will similarly get garbage collected when there is no longer any reference to them(ie, the end of the while loop).

Answer (score 0):

Both the Java object and the native memory are freed at the same time by the garbage collector.

However, note that because the garbage collector doesn’t work well at cleaning up direct buffers, it’s best to allocate and reuse long-lived direct buffers instead of creating and abandoning new ones.

Answer (score -2):

> when a directbytebuffer is allocated, its not subject to garbage
>   collection

Where did you get that idea? It's not correct. Are you getting them mixed up with MappedByteBuffers?