# Does Java has any strategy for collecting bytebuffer's from nio?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I have a lot of small `ByteBuffer`s. Does Java has any strategy for garbage collection of these `ByteBuffer`s?

Comment: Yes, it's the normal garbage collector.

Comment: Only the references to the bytebuffer's are normally collected

Comment: This could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854398/how-to-garbage-collect-a-direct-buffer-java

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697709/are-java-directbytebuffer-wrappers-garbage-collected