# I wonder if netty's directBytebuf will be automatically recycled

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, netty, nio

The Java nio DirectByteBuffer will be managed by the JVM and the gc will recycle the memory out of the heap. I wonder if netty's directBytebuf will be automatically recycled or if it must be manually released

Comment: You may want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647048/why-do-we-need-to-manually-handle-reference-counting-for-netty-bytebuf-if-jvm-gc/28843003#28843003

Answer (score 1):

When accessing things like `PooledDirectByteBuf`, it's usually the responsibility of the last accessor to release. `ByteBuf` in Netty is reference counted, and thus the active number of references needs to be updated correctly, to make something eligible for deallocation.

Comment: I know this, but I wonder if Directbuf will be reclaimed by the gc if I forget to release it manually

Comment: If you don't call `release()`, this will likely lead to leaks, esp. with pooled buffers. For reclamation by the garbage collector, there's an indirect relation [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697709/are-java-directbytebuffer-wrappers-garbage-collected)

Comment: I know that Java nio's DirectBuffer use "cleanner" to recycle the memory out of the heap during garbage collection, but I don't see netty's DirectBuf with "cleanner" code